# jquery function not working on multiple rows

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table generated by jQuery, and a function that triggers an event when pressing ENTER. 
The table generates correctly, but the function only works in the first wor of the table.

My html for the table is as follows:

```
<table border="1" id="PlantillaTable" name="PlantillaTable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Cargo</th>
        <th colspan="12" scope="col">Escenario de Registro</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Folio</td>
        <td colspan="2">Propietario</td>
        <td >Grupo</td>
        <td >Edad</td>
        <td colspan="2">Folio</td>
        <td colspan="2">Suplente</td>
        <td >Grupo</td>
        <td >Edad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="FilaTable">
        <th scope="row" col="1" row="1">Cargo</th>
        <td col="2" row="1">LISTA</td>
        <td col="3" row="1">
            <input type="text" id="AspiranteField" name="AspiranteField" placeholder="FOLIO" />
        </td>
        <td col="4" row="1">FOTO</td>
        <td col="5" row="1">NOMBRE</td>
        <td col="6" row="1">GRUPO</td>
        <td col="7" row="1">EDAD</td>
        <td col="8" row="1">LISTA</td>
        <td col="9" row="1">
            <input type="text" id="AspiranteField" name="AspiranteField" placeholder="FOLIO" />
        </td>
        <td col="10" row="1">FOTO</td>
        <td col="11" row="1">NOMBRE</td>
        <td col="12" row="1">GRUPO</td>
        <td col="13" row="1">EDAD</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And my function is as follows:

```
$.fn.pressEnter = function(fn) {  
    return this.each(function() {  
        $(this).bind('enterPress', fn);
        $(this).keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13)
            {
              $(this).trigger("enterPress");
            }
        })
    });  
 }; 

$('input').pressEnter(function(){
    var trid = ($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
    var opcion = ($(this).closest('td').index());
    var valor = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("php/getAspiranteNombre.php?AspiranteId="+valor,function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) {
            if(opcion < 4)
            {
                $("#"+trid+" td").eq(3).html('<p>'+item.NAME+'</p>');
                $("#"+trid+" td").eq(4).html('<p>'+item.GRUPO+'</p>');
                $.getJSON("php/getFoto.php?AspiranteId="+valor,function(data2){
                    $("#"+trid+" td").eq(2).html('<img src="aspiranteFoto/thumb_'+data2+'" width="50px" height="50px"/>');
                });
                $.getJSON("php/getEdad.php?Nacimiento="+item.EDAD,function(data3){
                    $("#"+trid+" td").eq(5).html('<p>'+data3+'</p>');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $("#"+trid+" td").eq(9).html('<p>'+item.NAME+'</p>');
                $("#"+trid+" td").eq(10).html('<p>'+item.GRUPO+'</p>');
                $.getJSON("php/getFoto.php?AspiranteId="+valor,function(data2){
                    $("#"+trid+" td").eq(8).html('<img src="aspiranteFoto/thumb_'+data2+'" width="50px" height="50px"/>');
                });
                $.getJSON("php/getEdad.php?Nacimiento="+item.EDAD,function(data3){
                    $("#"+trid+" td").eq(11).html('<p>'+data3+'</p>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Which basically asks for a value in a database and places it in the  spaces. The problem is that, in the first row of the table (dynamically generated) the function works perfectly, but in the subsequent rows it doesn't do anything.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the way to this one:

```
$("#PlantillaTable").find("input").keyup(function(ev) {
    if (ev.which === 13 ) {
      //yout code here...
    }
});
```

Attaches to all input values inside this table the enter button handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/jkfL2v5s/

Comment: I still have the same problem when hitting "enter". the first line of the table works great, but for the rest of the table it doesn't do anything. The table has more that 10 rows added though jQuery clone method.

Comment: I was able to workaround the problem that I had by generating the skeleton of my table first and then add the functionality. Your code helped me a lot to simplify the process of the ENTER function that I had. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You first have to loop through each `tr` separately, then you can target the `td`'s inside.

You can loop through the rows using [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) like this:

```
$("table tr").each(function(i,v){

  $(this).find("td:eq(3)").html('<p>'+item.NAME+'</p>');
  ....

});
```

and it will go through all your rows, not just the first one.

Comment: This option will change EVERY td in my table that has the td index 3, and I need to modify only the row where the input has been hit.

Comment: It's also just an example, for getting to each row. You should be able to infer from that code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This code is actually helpful, however my problem seems to be that the function that handles the ENTER event seems to be loading before my table is constructed. I am now looking for a solution to that. Thanks a lot!